# I am trying to append a map to a map of same Name in Mule . But the the values are getting overwritten

Tags: mule, esb, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

I am trying to append a map to a map with the same Name in Mule Dataweave, but the the values are getting overwritten.

[image: First map]
Just after this I am trying to map other values that I store in flow vars:

[image: Second Image]

Basically, say if there are 11 records already populated in `010_HL_Loop` element through the 1st loop, I want the next loop to start from the 11th `10_HL_Loop` element and add other map elements to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with this snippet in dataweave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
flatten (payload ++ flowVars.getVehicleInfo)
```

You need to make sure that both the payload and the flow variable are an array